# Controlling a Firefox Extension via Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, watir

Is it possible, using javascript, to control an overlay firefox extension? I've extracted the contents of the extension and have identified what functions/methods I need to run, but they are not accessible within the scope of the console.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You can have the extension listen for an _Event_ on say `window`, then `dispatchEvent` from the _JavaScript_ on the page (this requires modifying the extension's code).

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I heard you can get the top level wrapper of any addon and use any function from there. I asked on a forum where this was mentioend before will update you with what I hear back.

Comment: @Noit thanks please let me know. I'm surprised this information has been so hard to find thus far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it possible to interact with other add-ons, given the right circumstances.

My test case here will be `com.googlecode.sqlitemanager.openInOwnWindow()`, which is part of the [`SqliteManager` addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

1. In newer builds (I'm using Nightly), there is the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox). With it is is as simple as opening a toolbox and executing `com.googlecode.sqlitemanager.openInOwnWindow()` in the Console.
2. You may instead use the Browser Console (or any chrome enabled WebDev Console for that matter, e.g. the Console of "about:newtab"). But you need some boilerplate code to first find the browser window. So here is the code you can execute there: `var bwin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser"); bwin.com.googlecode.sqlitemanager.openInOwnWindow()`
3. Again, [enable chrome debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools_Toolbox#Settings). Then open a Scratchpad and switch to *Chrome* in the *Environment* menu. Now executing `com.googlecode.sqlitemanager.openInOwnWindow()` in our Scratchpad will work.
4. You may of course write your own overlay add-on.
5. As a last resort, patch the add-on itself.
6. Bootstrapped/SDK add-ons: you can load `XPIProvider.jsm` (which changed location recently) and get to the bootstrapped scope (run environment of `bootstrap.js`) via [`XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes[addonID]`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/internal/XPIProvider.jsm#4318), and take it from there (use whatever is in the bootstrap scope, e.g. the SDK loader).

Now about the *right circumstances*: If and how you can interact with a certain add-on depends on the add-on. Add-ons may have global symbols in their overlay and hence browser window, such as in the example I used. Or may use (to some extend) JS code modules. Or have their own custom loader stuff (e.g. AdBlock Plus has their own `require()`-like stuff and SDK add-ons have their own loader, which isn't exactly easy to infiltate)...

Since your question is rather unspecific, I'll leave it at this.

**Edit by question asker:** This is correct, however I figured I'd add an example of the code I ended up using in the end, which was in fact taken directly from mozilla's developer network website:

In my chrome js:

```
var myExtension = {
  myListener: function(evt) {
   IprPreferences.setFreshIpStatus(true); // replace with whatever you want to 'fire' in the extension
  }
}

document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) { myExtension.myListener(e); }, false, true);
// The last value is a Mozilla-specific value to indicate untrusted content is allowed to trigger the event.
```

In the web content:

```
var element = document.createElement("MyExtensionDataElement");
element.setAttribute("attribute1", "foobar");
element.setAttribute("attribute2", "hello world");
document.documentElement.appendChild(element);

var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("MyExtensionEvent", true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: This is possible if the addon injects its addon module into each window (as was the method with overlay addons) what about with bootstrap addons?

Comment: @Noitidart Bootstrapped add-ons are indeed harder to get to. And again, it depends on the actual implementation what best to use. But you can always load XPIProvider.jsm and get to the bootstrapped scope (run environment of bootstrap.js) via [`XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes[addonID]`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/internal/XPIProvider.jsm#4318)

Comment: No way!! + a thousand rep for this reply!! I have been looking for that answer for a looooong time!!! Thanks nmaier!!! I can link you to many topics of me asking this haha! Thanks man!!

Comment: Hey man question, I found XPIProvider.jsm but it has no exported symbols. [MXR LINK - XPIProvider.jsm](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/internal/XPIProvider.jsm) how would I access this? Like after import how can I use? Its not a return function so it doesnt set a variable to anything right? I did it like this is it correct way? `var XPIScope = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm");
console.log(XPIScope.XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes['ghForkable@jetpack'])`

Comment: @nmaier I'd also be interested in more details on #6. Please see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490487/access-add-on-sdk-module-from-the-scratchpad). Thanks

Comment: Why do they keep moving this around?? It got moved again in FF30, its now at *resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm* so you have to import now with `Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm')`

Answer (score 1):

## Update for Firefox 47 and up

Things changed drastically in Firefox 47. This is the new way to access it.

```
var XPIScope = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm');
var addonid = 'Profilist@jetpack';
var scope = XPIScope.XPIProvider.activeAddons.get(addonid).bootstrapScope
```

## Old way for < Firefox 47

Update for methods of today

Typically you will do so like this:

If i wanted to get into AdBlocks scope, I check AdBlock id, it is `{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}` so I would go:

```
var XPIScope = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm');
var adblockScope = XPIScope.XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes['{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}'];
```

You can now tap into anything there.

Another example, I have an addon installed with id `NativeShot@jetpack`

I would tap into it like this:

```
var XPIScope = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm');
var nativeshotScope = XPIScope.XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes['NativeShot@jetpack'];
```

if you do `console.log(nativeshotScope)` you will see all that is inside.