# Access Add-on SDK module from the scratchpad

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like to test small snippets of my add-on code using the scratchpad. In this case, I'm trying to access the notifications module like so:

```
const { notify } = require("sdk/notifications");
notify({
  //My notification's options
});
```

As expected, I get the error `Exception: require is not defined`. As the Add-on SDK is packaged with Firefox, I'm wondering if there's a way to access the modules directly from the scratchpad. Thanks.

---

Edit: After some Googling, I found [scratch-kit (github)](https://github.com/Gozala/scratch-kit/), an add-on that does exactly what I'm trying to do. But it is [unfortunately broken](https://github.com/Gozala/scratch-kit/issues/16), so I've [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985181) in hopes that this functionality will be added to the devtools.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057888/controlling-a-firefox-extension-via-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there isn't a way to do this.  A few things could happen to make this possible which people can watch/contribute:

1. [scratch-kit](https://github.com/Gozala/scratch-kit/) is updated
2. [native jetpack](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=915376) is completed and is integrated with itchpad (which should replace scratch kit).  [I made an example which I blogged about but it's not ready for release yet](http://work.erikvold.com/devtools/2014/02/23/my-devtools-work-week-hack.html).

Answer (score 4):

By now there is a relatively simple way to do this. The following code works fine if executed in privileged context (meaning switching Scratchpad's environment to "Browser"):

```js
let {require} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js", {});
let {notify} = require("sdk/notifications");
```

This is supported starting with Firefox 36 but not really documented as of now - meaning that this might stop working in future.

For reference: [pull request #1679](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/pull/1679) added this functionality (not meant for external use it seems).

Comment: This also works in the global browser console (tested in Firefox 42 by using `require('sdk/notifications').notify({title:'Hello world'})` after importing `require` as you've shown).