# Accessing Firefox Add-on SDK from Bootstrapped extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need access to the [bootstrap entry points](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Bootstrap_entry_points) but also want access to the nice features that the Firefox [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) provides.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Removed the [tag:firefox-os] tag... Firefox OS does not support extensions at the moment (if ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, the most elegant option seems to be the use of [the experimental `--templatedir=TEMPLATEDIR` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#Experimental_Options_3) that appears perfectly suited for doing precisely this (using a custom `bootstrap.js` file). This allows me to hook into those install/uninstall functions (if necessary) and use the rest of the SDK like normal.

Edit: someone asked me to give a clarification on how `cfx` is to be used with `--templatedir`.

1. Copy somewhere the directory called `app-extension` that contains the `bootstrap.js`, `application.ini`, and `install.rdf` files in it from the downloaded SDK.
2. Run your `cfx xpi` command like regular but add `--templatedir=path/to/cloned/directory` to the options.

Comment: Thanks for sharing man. Did you see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057888/controlling-a-firefox-extension-via-javascript/22099148#22099148

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Loader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/_loader). This is the same thing that the SDK uses and you can actually set it up to be able to load SDK modules. Although IIRC this isn't well documented and there are some subtle details on how you need to do the setup or some SDK modules will not work correctly.

I suggest you read the linked documentation above and then use the SDK [`bootstrap.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/0ecebf288b09343f7fb8012c11c87f4d0706b1e5/app-extension/bootstrap.js) as a base and strip it down as needed (e.g. remove all those fancy `test` stuff).

Also, to give another example, @erikvold (who works or worked on the SDK team as well) implemented minimal support for [internally loading (some) SDK modules in Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/blob/de4b50f1bb39575d6154063718d6760be5e05e11/extension/modules/constants.js#L135).

Comment: Do I understand correctly: I create an Add-on SDK app (via [`cfx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx)?), modify `bootstrap.js` to use my `(un)install` functions, and then load the rest of my code using `Loader`?

Comment: You could do that, but AMO would likely reject it as a tempered-with SDK add-on. I suggest you simply copy bootstrap.js and edit/strip it to work without the unneeded SDK cruft (SDK tests, harness-options processing, etc).

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Regular (non SDK add-ons) don't get rejected (right?), so can't I just submit it as one of those? I don't plan on advertising it as SDK if I've messed with it (I didn't even know there were different categories you could submit extensions under). P.S. I'm like *this* close to giving you that checkmark, hopefully I'll find out in today's coding session if this approach works. :P

Comment: That's due to limitations in the review system and/or inconsistencies in the review policies.

Comment: Turns out the SDK [provides an elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348128/1781435). Thank you for your help though!