# Interacting with firefox addons by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

My case is when the user press f10 i want to run the copy paste addons in Firefox. 
in the case i want to implement a listener for this key and when this key pressed  run the addons and copy text to the clipboard.
How i  can use the Firefox addons to copy the text by javascript?

Comment: So you want to access the scope of an existing add-on? See here: [StackOverflow :: Controlling a Firefox Extension via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057888/controlling-a-firefox-extension-via-javascript/22099148#22099148)

Answer (score 1):

This copies text to the native clipboard. Not logical clipboard. Apparently those are different things.

```
var gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
gClipboardHelper.copyString("Put me on the clipboard, please.")
```