# Calling a Firefox Extension function from Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

I want to call a function from a JavaScript file loaded in Firefox browser from Selenium in C#.

I want to call a function present in a Firefox extension returning some data; I want that data in my C# code.

How can I call this method using Selenium?

Comment: I dont know selenium but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057888/controlling-a-firefox-extension-via-javascript/22099148#22099148 it also likely depends on the extension. Any specific extension you had in mind? If its your own extension there are a bunch of ways you can listen to outside communication.

Comment: yes I want to interact with Zotero's extension to scrape data and I want that scraped data in my c#.net application for this I want to call a function of Zotero's extension from C# application